# Trying to create a directory immediately after a successful deleteIfExists throws AccessDenied Exception

Tags: java, delete-file, access-denied

I am trying to create a file , and prior to that delete it if it exists. My problem is that whenever i have a successful delete operation and immediately after that try to create the same folder , it fails with AccessDenied. The method description(for both deleteIfExists and createDirectory) does not mention such behavior , so i guess i am doing something wrong .

This is the code :

```
package nio2;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Path existing = Paths.get("nio2//alpha//inner.txt"); // already existing
        Path cpytarget = Paths.get("nio2//alphacpy//inner.txt"); // file to be created 
        Path target = Paths.get("nio2//alphacpy");//
        try{
            if(Files.exists(cpytarget))
            {
                Files.list(target).forEach(Test::WrappedDeleteIfExists); // deleting files inside folder
                System.out.println("Deleting the directory if it exists - alphaCpy\t" +  Files.deleteIfExists(target));//deleting
            }
            else
                System.out.println("It does not exist, no need to delete anything");
            System.out.println("Creating alphaCpy\t" + Files.createDirectory(target));//creating
            System.out.println("copying inner.txt to the new directory\t" + Files.copy(existing,cpytarget));
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void WrappedDeleteIfExists(Path in)
    {
        try{
            System.out.println("Deleting files inside the folder\t" + Files.deleteIfExists(in));
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

So in a successful run ( when there is no delete ) . this is the output

```
It does not exist, no need to delete anything
Creating alphaCpy       nio2\alphacpy
copying inner.txt to the new directory  nio2\alphacpy\inner.txt
```

If i run it after that when the folder and file are already existing  i get the exception:

```
Deleting files inside the folder        true
Deleting the directory if it exists - alphaCpy  true
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: nio2\alphacpy
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:504)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
        at nio2.Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

Next run is again successful , as it has been already deleted and so on. So the question is what is causing the AccessDenied exception ? Have in mind that the file is not open/used, and the relative paths are valid.

EDIT: Ok i managed to correct it but honestly i still can not explain to myself the initial problem. So i will be grateful if someone can help with that. I went from using a Stream to File[] in order to delete the file inside the folder. After i did that it works like a charm.

Here is the corrected code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Path existing = Paths.get("E:/work/Java/Tests/alpha/inner.txt"); // already existing
        Path cpytarget = Paths.get("E:/work/Java/Tests/alphacpy/inner.txt"); // file to be created 
        Path target = Paths.get("E:/work/Java/Tests/alphacpy");//
        File fileTarget = new File("E:/work/Java/Tests/alphacpy");      
        try{
            if(Files.exists(cpytarget))
            {
                WrappedDeleteIfExists(fileTarget.listFiles()); // CHANGED , no longer using Stream<Path> pipeline to go through the file list
                // deleting files inside folder
                System.out.println("Deleting the directory if it exists - alphaCpy\t" +  Files.deleteIfExists(target));//deleting
            }
            else
                System.out.println("It does not exist, no need to delete anything");
            System.out.println(Files.exists(target));

            System.out.println("Creating alphaCpy\t" + Files.createDirectory(target));//creating
            System.out.println("copying inner.txt to the new directory\t" + Files.copy(existing,cpytarget));
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // CHANGED - using File[] instead of Path
    public static void WrappedDeleteIfExists(File[] in)
    {
        for(int i =0;i<in.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Deleting files inside the folder\t" +in[i].delete());
        }

    }
```

Obviously the Stream operations are keeping it locked somehow, even after finishing, but this is not an IO Stream( or is it with Files.list()??) that i can close , so what can i do in order to make it work with Stream - its not something Closable or something that trying to force GC on makes sense.

Comment: If you step through the code one line at a time in your debugger do you still see the same error? If not, it could be the delete operation returns as soon as the delete is accepted by the OS but the OS takes a finite time (tens to hundreds of milliseconds) to complete deletion of the directory.  If that is the case you will have to insert a retry loop with exponential backoff up to, say, 1 second.  You can't retry indefinitely because there might be a real access-denied condition.

Comment: Same result in the debugger step by step. Also tried with adding Thread.sleep(5000); , so that the main thread waits for a couple of seconds after the delete. No change in the results.

Comment: Why do you use double _forward_ slashes. You shouldn't do that. Try single forward slashes.  Also, print out the value of `Files.exists(target)` after the delete operation, to see what the NIO stack thinks about the existence of the directory.

Comment: I tried that as well, it returns false- not existing. Also tried on a separate hard drive + pc restart. Thanks about the slashes. :)

Comment: I'm out of ideas. You might check the [Java bug database](http://bugs.java.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for `Files.list(Path)` states:

> This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or
> similar control structure to ensure that the stream's open directory
> is closed promptly after the stream's operations have completed.

The fix is simply to ensure that all use of `Files.list()` and `Files.find()` streams are closed after use, best done with try with resources handling:

```
try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(target)) {
    // do your str.forEach() calls with Files.deleteIfExists
    stream.forEach(Test::WrappedDeleteIfExists);
}
```

Without the above fix - or switch to `File.listFiles()` - you can get weird behaviour in Windows Explorer: the deleted directory appears to exist but has no contents, and all operations report "Access Denied" errors. The problem remains until the current VM process ends.